# Why is my code failing to calculate a score in a game of Greed?

Tags: c

**The Problem**

Greed is a dice game played with five six-sided dice. Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to score a throw according to these rules. You will always be given an array with five six-sided dice values.

---

- Three 1's => 1000 points
- Three 6's =>  600 points
- Three 5's =>  500 points
- Three 4's =>  400 points
- Three 3's =>  300 points
- Three 2's =>  200 points
- One   1   =>  100 points
- One   5   =>   50 point

A single dice can only be counted once in each roll. For example, a given "5" can only count as part of a triplet (contributing to the 500 points) or as a single 50 points, but not both in the same roll.

---

**Example scoring:**

Throw     |  Score

5 1 3 4 1 |  250:  50 (for the 5) + 2 * 100 (for the 1s)

1 1 1 3 1 |  1100: 1000 (for three 1s) + 100 (for the other 1)

2 4 4 5 4 |  450:  400 (for three 4s) + 50 (for the 5)

**My code**

```
int score(const int dice[5]) {   
    int ones=0;
    int twos=0;
    int threes=0;
    int fours=0;
    int fives=0;
    int sixes=0;
    int total = 0;
      
    //counting roll
    for (int i=0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (dice[i] == 1){
            ones++;
        }
        else if(dice[i] == 2){
            twos++;
        }
        else if(dice[i] == 3){
            threes++;
        }
        else if(dice[i] == 4){
            fours++;
        }
        else if(dice[i] == 5){
            fives++;
        }
        else if(dice[i] == 6){
            sixes++;
        }
    }
      
    //adding value to roll
    if(ones == 1){
        total = total + 100;
    }
    else if (ones == 2){
        total = total + 200;
    }
    else if (ones == 3){
        total = total + 1000;
    }
    else if(ones == 4){
        total = total + 1100;
    }
    else if (ones == 5){
        total = total + 1200;
    }
    else if(ones == 6){
        total = total + 2000;
    }
      
    if(twos == 3){
        total = total + 200;
    }
    else if (twos == 6){
        total = total + 400;
    }
      
    if(threes == 3){
        total = total + 300;
    }
    else if (threes == 6){
        total = total + 600;
    }
      
    if(fours == 3){
        total = total + 400;
    }
    else if(fours == 6){
        total = total + 800;
    }
      
    if(fives == 1){
        total = total + 50;
    }
    else if (fives == 2){
        total = total + 100;
    }
    else if(fives == 3){
        total = total + 500;
    }
    else if (fives == 4){
        total = total + 550;
    }
    else if (fives == 5){
        total = total + 600;
    }
    else if (fives == 6){
        total = total + 1000;
    }
      
    if(sixes == 3){
        total = total + 600;
    }
    else if(sixes == 6){
        total = total + 1200;
    }
      
    return total;
}
```

---

**My errors:**

[image]

---

**My Question**

What am I missing in this code? I thought I considered every possibility.

Comment: Undefined behavior for accessing beyond the bounds of an object.

Comment: Try debugging.  And paying attention to verbose warnings.  And terrible coding style with lots of gaps possible (and present)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function prototype

```
int score(const int dice[5])
```

as well as your own description, states that five (`5`) dices are thrown.

But in the loop

```
for (int i=0; i < 6; i++)
```

you access the sixth element of an array that has only five elements (`dice[5]`). In this way the behavior is undefined, meaning that you could have a wrong count of the throws and a wrong total.

For the same reason, checks like

```
else if(ones == 6){
    total = total + 2000;
}
```

are useless as you can never have "six of a kind".

---

Here it is a possible corrected (and optimized) version of your code:

```
int score(const int dice[5]) {
    int diceCounts[6] = { 0 };
    int total = 0;
  
    //counting roll
    //the numbers of throws of 'n' is contained into diceCounts[n-1]
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) 
    {
        if(dice[i]>=0 && dice[i] <= 6)
      
      ++diceCounts[dice[i]-1];
    }
  
    //adding value to roll
    if(diceCounts[0] >= 3){ //1
        total += 1000
        diceCounts[0] -= 3;
    }
    total += diceCounts[0] * 100;
 
    for (int i=1; i<6; i++)
    {
        if(diceCounts[i] >= 3){ //2...6
            total += i*100
            diceCounts[i] -= 3;
        }
    }
    
    total += diceCounts[4] * 50;
  
  return total;  
}
```

Suggestions:

- Create an array of six elements containing the numbers of throws of each number 'n' (contained into `n-1`-th element of the array)
- For each number, check if it has at least 3 occurrences. In that case update the total accordingly * Manage the case 1 separately. All the other numbers provide a `x*100` bonus
- Subtract 3 to the number of occurrences. That will be useful for case 5, in which you will multiply the reminder with 50 (the bonus of a single 5).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't handle all the cases... if you have 4 3s and one something else, it should count 300 but it counts 0 because you don't have a case for 4 3s (it should be the same as 3 3s)

Same for 4s.

I'd probably have written it as a loop where it removes the count as it uses it then handles any leftovers in another loop until a loop finds no score, but this will work if you add the cases you missed and stop iterating at index 4 which is the 5th element of your 5-element array.